# Create a Map<String,List<Integer>>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create a `Map<String,List<Integer>>`. The challenge here is to create the list if the key does not exist otherwise add the new integer using the current key to get the current list. 
I have worked something that is really close but I don't know how to refer to the current map to get the list.

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"even","odd"});
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7});
//This is what i want returned: Map<String, List<Integer>> myMap=null;
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = strList.stream().flatMap(s -> intList.stream()
.map(i -> Maps.immutableEntry(s,i))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The values need to be created by calling a function like below which expects 3 parameters the current key, and value plus the current list.:

```
static public List<Integer> testFunc(String key, Integer i, List<Integer>list){
    if(list == null){
        list = new ArrayList();
    }
    list.add(i * key.hashCode());
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the expected result is?

Comment: I need Map<String, List<Integer>>. The list contains all the integers that are odd or even. The map should have two entries: "even"->[2,4,6] and "odd"->[1,3,5,7]

Comment: What are the possible values for `strList`? Only `"even"` and `"odd"`? In that case, you don't need a stream at all. I guess this is a simplified example but how do you intend to map the String `"even"` to `i -> i % 2 == 0` dynamically?

Comment: Fabio, I don't see how the `testFunc` you added would result in "even"->[2,4,6] and "odd"->[1,3,5,7].  Does the example output you gave in your comment above need to be updated, or does this need to accept a BiFunction that produces the list, which might be a reference to testFunc, or another function that would result in the example output you provided?

Comment: Is the parameter list for testFunc a requirement, or could you consider a solution that uses a BiFunction<String,Integer,List<Integer>> (like  `testFunc(String key, Integer i)`) and lets the Stream logic create the Lists for the Map values?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this behavior would be to use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) with your own classifier:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = 
    intList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"));
```

Comment: The code I posted is actually a very simplify version of what I need to do. First you answer uses the key values. In my real case I have a large unknown number of keys. The second part is to calculate the value of each map I have to actually call a function that expects the List or null if it is empty.

Comment: @Fabio Then be more clearer about what you want. Mureinik answers your question perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Your question really needs more clarity.  My best guess given everything you have said so far is that you have a list of keys, a list of input values (Integers) a function that takes a key and an input integer, calculates an output integer and adds the result integer to a list value in a map by key.

It sounds like your testFunc must be able to perform a variety of operations, not just "even" and "odd". It also sounds like the values in `intList` could be used in more than one `List`, not just partitioned into buckets, so using my imagination in the absence of better details, I envision it as something that might look like

```
static Optional<Integer> testFunc(String key, int intVal){
    switch(key){
        case "even": return Optional.of(intVal).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0);  // return intVal if key is "even" and i is even
        case "odd": return Optional.of(intVal).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0);   // return intVal if key is "odd" and i is odd
        case "pos": return Optional.of(intVal).filter(i -> i > 0);        // return intVal if key is "pos" and i is positive
        case "neg": return Optional.of(intVal).filter(i -> i < 0);        // return intVal if key is "neg" and i is negative
        default: return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

I use `Optional` here because a given integer `i` might not apply to a given key.  The filters reduce the `Optional<Integer>` to `Optional.empty()` if `i` doesn't apply to the given key.

The stream below does a straight map of a given key from `strList` to the list of integers that apply to it.  It does this by considering each key, one at a time, and selecting the values from intList that apply and collecting them to a `List`.

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("even", "odd", "pos", "neg");
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3);
Map<String,List<Integer>> results = strList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> intList.stream()
                    .map(i -> testFunc(s, i)).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ));
System.out.println(results);
```

The result is

```
{neg=[-3, -2, -1], pos=[1, 2, 3], even=[-2, 0, 2], odd=[-3, -1, 1, 3]}
```

Is this the kind of result you want?

One of the problems I struggled with and wished more clarity about was that your "even"/"odd" example seemed to apply a Predicate to the intList, filtering just even numbers for "even" and just odd numbers for "odd"; while your testFunc example maps a value out for every value from intList for every value in strList.  If your testFunc really does need to both map values and filter values, it will be hard for you to do that using Streams, because `map()` and `filter()` are separate stream operations. You can kind of do both a `map()` and `filter()` if you do a `map()` to an `Optional` that has had a `filter()` applied to it, which is what I do in the example above, then applying a `filter(Optional::isPresent)` to filter out the things that didn't meet the boolean test in `testFunc`, then applying `filter(Optional::get)` to unwrap the `Integer` from the `Optional` wrapper.